# EF code first Reference key as primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

Landed up in a quite ridiculous situation here.

I'm coding in EF core, ASP.NET core, Visual Studio 2017 community.

I have a model which does not have a primary key like:

```
public class LoginRecord
{
    public User User { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastLogin { get; set; }
    public int LoginCount { get; set; } 
}
```

where `User` is a table with all the fields like name, email etc.

When I do `add-migration`, an error pops up saying:

> The entity type 'LoginRecord' requires a primary key to be defined.

Then I tried by adding the `[Key]` annotation to the `UserId` field like this:

```
public class LoginRecord
{
    public User User { get; set; }

    [Key]    
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastLogin { get; set; }
    public int LoginCount { get; set; } 
}
```

but now, EF creates a new column called `UserId1` which becomes the foreign key.

I need the `UserId` to be just a reference key and don't need a primary key for this table.

Is it possible? If yes please help!

Comment: EF needs a primary key for **each table** - and so do you ...

Comment: You can try to use composed primary key. Say UserId + LastLogin + Count, but I am not sure if it works)

Comment: just add LoginRecordId as primary key

Comment: @marc_s You mean to say.. no workaround?

Comment: **NO** - EF (and any properly designed table) **must have** a primary key. Period.

Comment: You should probably configure the relation between User and LoginRecord as 1:1.

Comment: so adding the Id column would be the best solution... Is that what you say? @marc_s

Comment: @GertArnold The problem is that I will have multiple login records with the time stamp! count is just to have a track! no so necessary.

Comment: Share `User` class

Answer (score 0):

You should add an primary key.
I've learned that every table should get a field which is named like the table + id. You could also name it id if you like it more. :)
So that every record gets unique.

So I would advice you to change your model to something like this:

```
public class LoginRecord
{
  [Key]
  public int LoginRecordID {get; set;}

  public User User { get; set; }

  public int UserId { get; set; }

  public DateTime LastLogin { get; set; }
  public int LoginCount { get; set; } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
[ForeignKey("UserId"), Column(Order = 0)]
public int UserId { get; set; }
```

Comment: Care to explain why?

Comment: I hope this just puts in my column as the first one...  but not a PKey...

Comment: Well, the `Column` attribute isn't relevant when the key is not composite. As sais in the comments, the actual point here is that `LoginRecord` needs a PK of its own.